# Hubot: modular scripts

Tags: coffeescript, hubot

I want to build a modular script system for my hubot instance.

e.g.: My colleagues can write on modules which should follow a certain schema.

Within these modules I want to export let's say a json object which should automatically be picked up by my central "hub" scripts.

Like this:

- node_modules/work-hub.coffee
- node_modules/work-testcommand.coffee
- node_modules/work-weather.coffee

Within the testcommand and the weather scripts I want to somehow export this kind of json:

```
{
  "command": "!test"
  "help": "Help for the test command"
}
```

Within the hub command I want to pickup those json objects, so whenever someone writes "!test" it should call a specific function of the testcommand.coffee and respond.

When calling "!help test" it should reply with the help command.

Is this somehow possible?

Thanks in advance!

Julian

Comment: i'm not sure I understand your question. each additional script you add to the scripts folder can add new functionality. each script is modular ... you add it or remove it... Could the reload script help you? https://github.com/github/hubot-scripts/blob/master/src/scripts/reload.coffee